# Eloquent: одни удалить, другие вставить

Tags: laravel, laravel5, eloquent

Задача тривиальная. Желательно что-то наподобие $user->flags->insertAndDeleteOther()

Вариант "удалить все вставить новые" не нравится.

`таблица User
 - id
 - email`

`таблица Flags
 - id
 - value`

`таблица UserFlags
 - user_id
 - flag_id`

С фронтенда приходит новый набор флагов, выставленных посредством чекбоксов.
Нужно занести новый набор в таблицу UserFlags.

Как это сделать средствами query builder, collection или иными средствами laravel с минимальным количеством циклов и обращений к БД из контроллера?

Comment: таблица Users. Flags, flag_user. Следуйте конвенции, упрощайте себе жизнь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понял у вас это модели Eloquent и это всё сделано через реляции судя по таблицам, тогда воспользуйтесь методом [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

```
$flags = [1, 2, 3];
$user->flags()->sync($flags);
```

Всё просто, в итоге удалит те что не пришли в массиве и добавит из массива те которых нет в БД, в документации есть ещё примеры, посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось. Правда понадобилось заменить hasMany на 
 belongsToMany!